# Can an array of numbers be transformed into an array of functions?

Tags: javascript

Newbie asking for help: I have an array of numbers that needs to be transformed to an array of functions that return the original numbers, so instead of calling `a[3]`, I need to call call `a[3]()`

E.g.:

```
[1,2,3] -> [
    function () {return 1;}, 
    function () {return 2;}, 
    function () {return 3;}
]
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Why in the world do you need to do this?  If you explain the real problem you're trying to solve rather than this particular solution, then we'll probably be able to help you find a much better way to attack the problem.  What you are asking for seems incredibly inefficient.  Create a unique function for every value in an array is wasteful and I'm 100% sure there is a better way to solve your real problem if you can tell us what you're really trying to do.

Comment: The answers below all result in inefficient code - that was the point of my previous paragraph.  It's simply dumb to create N function closures all to return values from an array.  If you explained the real problem, you could probably create one function and no closures that would solve the problem much more efficiently.  I was trying to help you find a BETTER way to solve your problem.  If you don't care to learn a better or more efficient way to do things, then obviously I can't make you.

Comment: My question was my problem. I typed it word by word from a print out. It was just an interesting question that I couldn't work out hence why I'm here. Maybe its a trick question on its own. But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the homework tag to it.  That would have also changed my response.

Comment: No its not homework, its a question I came across. Will keep the homework tag in mind for next time. Cheers buddy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    arr[i] = (function(i) { return function() { return i; } })(i);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bqhHK/)

Comment: Because before the edit, you didn't have the assignment there...? (It wasn't me who downvoted, just sayin').

Comment: Aaand I just realised that this doesn't actually answer the question :-p

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert( arr ) {
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        arr[i] = (function( a ) { return function() { return a; }; })( arr[i] );
    }
    return arr;
}​

var arr = convert( [1, 2, 3] );
```

Comment: @Bergi—surely you're kidding. This is precisely the kind of thing that `eval` and Function as a function are meant for. Sure they have a little more overhead in creating the function, but they avoid the (useless, memory consuming) closure of the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey there, I'm a newbie trying to work this out, so I just picked the first answer that actually worked. Are you saying your answer is better? Can you please give me a quick explanation?

Comment: @muudless The accepted answer converts the array to functions that return the index (i.e. `arr[0]()` returns `0`, not `1`)... not the corresponding number from the previous array.

Answer (score 1):

```
[1, 2, 3].map(function(num) {
    return function(){ return num; }
});
```

should do the task

Comment: Yeah, but not in all browsers.

Comment: Or use a function that doesn't need it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
function transform(a) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        result.push(function(value) {
            return function() {
                return value;
            }
        }(a[i]));

    return result;
}

var myArray = [1, 2, 3];
var transformed = transform(myArray);
```